# Linux: sd* exists in /sys/block but not found under /dev

Tags: linux, fibre-channel

I am operating an OpenStack cloud which is using Fibre channel to connect to backend storage. The issue I am facing is that sometimes disk, for example sdx, got a folder under /sys/block/sdx, but there is no corresponding device under /dev/ folder.

So my question is under what circumstances, will sdx exist under /sys/block but does not appear under /dev?

Comment: does the kernel log show anything useful?